# Add switch button in Azure Runbook

Tags: windows, powershell, azure

Can we add a radio button or switch button which execute two different functions when selected either of them in Azure RunBook say below VMNAME param. similar to Run on settings (Azure/ Hybrid Worker).

I did add a bool parameters, but it didn't show up in UI

```
param (
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)]
    [string] $subscriptionID = "testsubscription",

    [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)]
    [string] $resourceGroupName = "RG-test",

    [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)]
    [string] $vmName = "testserver"

    [Parameter (Mandatory = $false)]
    [bool]$WhatIf

    )
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> Can we add a radio button or switch button which execute two different functions when selected either of them in Azure RunBook.

I am not sure whether it is supported currently. If you have any idea, you coud give your [feedback](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/34192--general-feedback) to Azure team.
but you could use bool type or switch paramter to control which function should be executed.

> I did add a bool parameters, but it didn't show up in UI

bool parameters could be show up in the UI as dropdownlist. Please with following code.

```
param (
[Parameter(Mandatory=$false)]
[string] $subscriptionID = "testsubscription",

[Parameter(Mandatory=$false)]
[string] $resourceGroupName = "RG-test",

[Parameter(Mandatory=$false)]
[string] $vmName = "testserver", # miss "," in your code.

[Parameter (Mandatory = $false)]
[bool]$WhatIf

)
```

[image]

Comment: Cool.. thanks, is it possible to provide different functions like powering on a VM and powering off a VM based on a value.